# How to display payload on a webpage in Node-Red

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache, node-red

I currently have a setup where a websocket is pulling in a msg.payload that consists of a number. it goes into the template node.

The template node says "This is the payload {{payload}} !"

I'm expecting to see the number on the page but when i go to the page, it just shows me "This is the payload: [object Object] !"

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `{{JSON.stringify(payload)}}` to see what happens.

Comment: The mustache format used by the Template node does not support function calls like JSON.stringify within its tags.

Answer (score 1):

That suggests that `msg.payload` is not a simple number as you think, but is actually a JavaScript Object of some sort.

If you pass the message to a Debug node you can confirm exactly what it contains in the Debug sidebar. You can then identify the proper way to access its contents and update the Template accordingly.